# Pygame text optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm training with pygame and want to see if there's a better way to display text to specific coordinates than what I did there:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold.tff", 30, False)
textA = font.render("a", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(textA, ((2 * w - w / 2 - 8),(windowHeight - 7/8 *h)))
textB = font.render("b", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(textB, ((3 * w - w / 2 - 8),(windowHeight - 7/8 *h)))
textC = font.render("c", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(textC, ((4 * w - w / 2 - 8),(windowHeight - 7/8 *h)))
textD = font.render("d", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(textD, ((5 * w - w / 2 - 8),(windowHeight - 7/8 *h)))
textE = font.render("e", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(textE, ((6 * w - w / 2 - 8),(windowHeight - 7/8 *h)))
textF = font.render("f", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(textF, ((7 * w - w / 2 - 8),(windowHeight - 7/8 *h)))
textG = font.render("g", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(textG, ((8 * w - w / 2 - 8),(windowHeight - 7/8 *h)))
textH = font.render("h", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(textH, ((9 * w - w / 2 - 8),(windowHeight - 7/8 *h)))
text8 = font.render("8", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(text8, ((2 * w / 3),(2 * h - h / 2 - 10)))
text7 = font.render("7", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(text7, ((2 * w / 3),(3 * h - h / 2 - 10)))
text6 = font.render("6", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(text6, ((2 * w / 3),(4 * h - h / 2 - 10)))
text5 = font.render("5", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(text5, ((2 * w / 3),(5 * h - h / 2 - 10)))
text4 = font.render("4", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(text4, ((2 * w / 3),(6 * h - h / 2 - 10)))
text3 = font.render("3", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(text3, ((2 * w / 3),(7 * h - h / 2 - 10)))
text2 = font.render("2", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(text2, ((2 * w / 3),(8 * h - h / 2 - 10)))
text1 = font.render("1", True, black)
displaySurf.blit(text1, ((2 * w / 3),(9 * h - h / 2 - 10)))
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use a `for`-loop to draw the text. e.g.:

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold.tff", 30, False)
```

```py
for n in range(8):

    textCol = font.render(chr(ord('a') + n), True, black)
    displaySurf.blit(textCol, ((n+2)*w - w/2 - 8, windowHeight - 7/8 *h))

    textRow = font.render(str(8-n), True, black)
    displaySurf.blit(textRow, (2*w/3, (n+2)*h - h/2 - 10))
```

Note, [`chr(i)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer `i` and [`ord(c)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of a character.
So the characters from `a` to `h` can be get by `chr(ord('a') + n)`, where `n` is in range from 0 to 7.
[`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) is used to convert an integer value to a string.

---

For performance reasons you can render the text surfaces to a list for the rows and columns. Finally `.blit` the prepared surfaces to the display:

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold.tff", 30, False)
textColumns = [font.render(chr(ord('a') + n), True, black) for n in range(8)]
textRows    = [font.render(str(8-n), True, black) for n in range(8)]
```

```py
for n, t in enumerate(textColumns):
    displaySurf.blit(t, ((n+2)*w - w/2 - 8, windowHeight - 7/8 *h)) 
for n, t in enumerate(textRows):
    displaySurf.blit(t, (2*w/3, (n+2)*h - h/2 - 10))
```

Comment: Why, thank you!

This is an awful lot more elegant than what I had lol